# How to have shared logins between multiple Digital Experience sites with custom domains

Tags: community-builder, site.com, digital-experience

We have three digital experience sites on our Salesforce instance. One is like a portal, which simply contains links to the other two sites. Each of the three sites has a custom domain, something like this:

- portal.mycompany.com
- site1.mycompany.com
- site2.mycompany.com

These sites are accessible to customers (via external identity licences) and employees (via normal employee licences).

After logging in to **portal.mycompany.com**, when navigating to **site1.mycompany.com** or **site2.mycompany.com**, users are asked to login again.

Is it possible to change this behaviour so that users only have to login once, and their logins are shared across all three sites?

Comment: Each Digital Experience Site is its own, separate security boundary. To navigate between Sites without authenticating at each Site, you need to implement single sign-on via SAML: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sso_sites_portals_about.htm&type=5

Comment: @identigral you should make that an answer.